# Non-blocking servlets

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, concurrency, nio

So,

Lately I started to play with non-blocking, async servlets (Servlet 3.1). As far as I understood,
by using async servlets there is a possibility to release a working thread while a non-blocking
operation is being done, so basically none of the threads is blocked. So i started doing some
load tests using Gatling stress tol, I used Spring RestController to create two simple controllers -
one doing a blocking HTTP get using RestTemplate (Spring's HTTP client), and one doing non-blocking
requests using AsyncRestTemplate and after processing a message with a callback, so those 2 follow:

```
@RequestMapping("/non-blocking")
public DeferredResult<String> nonBlocking() throws IOException {

    DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<String>();

    AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();

    String URL ="http://localhost:8080/static.html";
    HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.GET;
    Class<String> responseType = String.class;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("params", headers);
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = restTemplate.exchange(URL, method, requestEntity, responseType);

    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
            deferredResult.setResult(result.getBody());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("Failure while processing");
        }
    });


    return deferredResult;
}


@RequestMapping("/blocking")
 public String blockingRouter() {

    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    LOG.logStartBlocking();

    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/static.html");

        status = result.getStatusCode();

        return result.getBody();

    } finally {
        System.out.println("Processing done");
    }
}
```

So, as you can see non-blocking is returning DefferedResult (Spring's Future abstraction) and if I
get it right, after sending a HTTP request, thread should be freed and some (probably) other thread
would return a response when it's available. Well, after doing some load tests with 200 concurrent users, test went terribly wrong for a non-blocking version. Threads were fine, but upon reaching 400 req/s, controller just stopped returning responses - it got stuck, probably because of too high response time. Blocking one responded to all of the requests with cca 1000 req/s. So the question is did I do a good testing or missed something because results were totally unexpected for me. Server used was Tomcat (+NIO connector) with 50 threads - hoped to prove that non-blocking won't use many threads and reach it till the end and that blocking will fail due to thread exhaustion but it didn't happen. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so you know Play Framework for Java and Scala make creating async webapps very easy.  You should consider it for future projects.

Comment: check out this blog, i think it will help you out: http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/04/22/c10k-developing-non-blocking-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/